# Запретить доступ к странице по url asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть две страницы, одна со списком юзеров, другая, которая открывается при нажатии edit в этом списке возле конкретного юзера. Например users.aspx и edituser.aspx. Нужно как-то запретить доступ к  edituser.aspx (например www.blabla.com/edituser.aspx), но чтобы был доступ к этой странице при условии, что я на нее попал со страницы users.aspx. Как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` - от честных людей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно рассмотреть [свойство Url.Referrer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string referrer = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null ? "" : HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
if(!referrer.ToLower().Contains("users"))
{
RedirectToAction("Access denied")
}
```

но у этого пути есть проблемы (рефер может быть пустым, ну и известная бага с Https тоже)

Второй путь - отправлять с ссылки проверку

`@Html.ActionLink("Method","Controller", new {bool show = true})`

(с поправкой на движок Razor)

а сам контроллер заполнить проверкой типа

`if(!show)
    RedirectToAction("Access denied")`

но и это зло - пользователь может создать машинно-понятный запрос типа
www.blabla.com/edituser.aspx?show=true

Остаётся только один правильный метод.
Разграничить пользователю доступ к методу edituser.aspx так же как к users.aspx, то есть на уровне бизнеслогики поместить их в один кластер доступа.

Старайтесь отделять слой приложения, что-бы view не знало о controller а контроллер не знал про БД